# Name of language of translation

Tags: java, database

I am unhappy with my entity-relation-namings.

The underliyng tables are named TRANSLATION and LANGUAGE.

To contains translations like

```
German is German in English
Deutsch is German in German
English is English in English
Englisch is English in German
```

I have the table

```
LANGUAGE
  ID (int pk)               <-- 1,2,3, ...  
  LANGTAG (varchar)         <-- en / de / fr / ...
TRANSLATION
  LOCAL_NAME (varchar 64)   <-- German, Allemand, Deutsch, ...
```

Now I need relations between them. In the Entity i have both sides, the owning side and the non-owning-side.

I started using this relations:

[image]

You see two FKs:

1. Translates (getter in Translations) -> Translations (getter in Language)
2. Into language (getter in Translations) -> Language Translations (getter in Language)

But I inspect my Language-Entity now and see this:

```
private Set<Translation> translations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = Translation.PROP_TRANSLATES)
public Set<Translation> getTranslations() {
    return translations;
}

public Language setTranslations(final Set<Translation> translations) {
    this.translations = translations;
    return this;
}

private Set<Translation> languageTranslations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = Translation.PROP_INTO_LANGUAGE)
public Set<Translation> getLanguageTranslations() {
    return languageTranslations;
}

public Language setLanguageTranslations(final Set<Translation> languageTranslations) {
    this.languageTranslations = languageTranslations;
    return this;
}
```

I think the naming is problematic because I do not know what getter to use if I need the translations.

Intuitivly, to get the Languages that has been translated from German I use

```
Language german = entityManager.createCriteria("FROM Language WHERE langtag='de'");
Set<Translations> languagesInGerman = german.getLanguageTranslations();
```

The getter looks absolutly strange but I have no idea for a renaming!

Comment: Maybe `german.getNatives()` but again I have no idea if i get a list of words translating German or a list of languages translated in german.

Comment: Did you write this code or was it generated?

Comment: I wrote it, why?

Comment: Just the way it was worded made it sound like it may have been generated code. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is this Language table part of a larger system? Why aren't the language names stored in resource bundles, as in how i18n is customarily done?

Comment: Its for articles written in different languages, articles are not keybased but resourcebundles are keybased. To be sure a article-translation has a language I use foreign keys.

Comment: Well, maybe`getLanguageNameInNativeLanguage`? There's actually a term for that: endonym (and exonym, see wiki). So, `getLanguageEndonym` or something similar would look prettier, but a layman of the app doesn't understand it. If language is something important in the app, I would use the academic term.

Comment: @slowy Good catch! Use that terms might be propulsive but brutal. If I really use them I must use them on both sides. Your comment is very good, can you put it as an possible answer?

Comment: Your translation mechanism, by look-up tables and word substitution, seems a lot like the approach taken by [Word Net](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/).  You might mine them for ideas.  I think though direct substitution like this is problematic. Other techniques analyses large amounts of native text to determine *context* words that are frequently used together.  This allows better idiomatic translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Proper answer from my comment in OP's question)

My proposal:

`getLanguageNameInNativeLanguage`

Other than that, there's a term for that: Endonym. See wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exonym_and_endonym

Quote:
*An endonym or autonym is an internal name for a geographical place, or a group of people, or a **language** or dialect.*

*For instance, "Germany" is the English language exonym, "Allemagne" is the French language exonym, and "Deutschland" is the endonym for the same country in Europe.*

`getLanguageEndonym()` or something similar would look prettier, but a layman of the app doesn't understand it. If language is something important in the app, I would use the "academic" term.